# Pinescript - ((time >= time_start) and (time <= time_end)) not working

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Trying to color the background of the chart when the time is between a time start and a time end. I've plotted the values of the start and end values I'm trying to use and the time is deffinetly between the values, yet it doesn't plot right. See Screen Shot 1 and 2
Code:

```
n_monday     = (dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday)
start_of_mon = n_monday and (ta.barssince(n_monday == false) == 1)

n_sunday     = (dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.sunday)
start_of_sun = n_sunday and (ta.barssince(n_sunday == false) == 1)


f_start_monday  = (ta.barssince (start_of_sun) == offset) ? true : na
f_monday        = ta.valuewhen (f_start_monday, time, 0)

f_start_tuesday = (ta.barssince (start_of_mon) == offset) ? true : na
f_tuesday       = ta.valuewhen (f_start_tuesday, time, 0)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if f_start_monday
    label.new (bar_index, 3000, str.tostring (f_monday / 100000))
if f_start_tuesday
    label.new (bar_index, 3000, str.tostring (f_tuesday / 100000))



hs_monday      = ((time >= f_monday) and (time <= f_tuesday))



bgcolor (hs_monday ? color.blue : na)
```

I've tried using bar_index instead which doesn't work at all. Rearanging the variables that the last use, rewording them, nothing seems to work, even though time is very clearly between the values given on the labels. (Note I did divide the text on the labels by 100000 for easy reading). **Thanks so much for your help in advance!**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, does `(dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday) ? true : false` return `true` if `(dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday)` is `true`? If so then you can just use `n_monday     = dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday` etc. instead to make it less complicated. Next those `== 1` are not Boolean comparisons, they are comparing Boolean values to numbers which is a discontinuity in variable types. (I know nothing of pine script, those are just things that look wrong from a general programming perspective.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton - yes, your right! That was still there because I originally used it with a plot to test it's functionality, which needed ```(dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday) ? true : na``` I just replaced na with false. for the ```==1``` problem, I'm taking ```(ta.barssince(n_monday == false)==1``` meaning if the number of bars since n_monday was false equals 1, then it's true. so int == int. I don't blame you for thinking that, pinescript is incredibly funky and has such little documentation, But thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to colour the background all the way from the first blue marker to the second one?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, from the red dash to the orange dash (orange is the only place where blue is showing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the precision, and the f_tuesday variable. I instead used `f_monday + 8400000`  (the same value as f_tuesday, just based off f_monday instead). All numbers used were absolutely the same and correct, and I have no idea why this worked instead of the former, pinescript am I right?!

I will accept my own answer as soon as stack overflow lets me, so sorry if you were trying to help because it says there hasn't been a solution!